# Prevent Concurrent Writes in Laravel

Tags: php, database, rest, laravel, concurrency

I have a laravel 5.2 app which receives a POST from clients when they arrive at a particular location. On occasion, the client fires two identical requests at the same time, but uses the same record (the last event, that was not part of these duplicate requests) to decide how to be handled.

With each request, I'm trying to prevent duplicate checkins/checkouts by determining if the client has already signed in or out of a same location by checking the last event for that user.

Eg:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Checkin;
use App\Models\Population;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CheckinApiController extends Controller {

    public function post(Request $request) {

        $uuid = $request->uuid;
        $isCheckin = $request->isCheckin;
        $locationId = $request->locationId;

        // get the last checkin for user matching this UUID
        $lastCheckin = Checkin::where("uuid", $uuid)
                               ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                               ->first();

        if ($isCheckin == $lastCheckin->isCheckin 
            && $locationId == $lastCheckin->locationId) {
/* Scenario 1:
 * if this post event is the same as the last record's checkin type
 * (checkin/checkout), and the locationIds are the same, this is a 
 * duplicate. Return an error code and message
 * In this case, both the duplicate requests see the same record,
 * and both are handled as duplicates
 */
            abort(403, 'duplicate');
        } else if ($isCheckin == true 
                   && $isCheckin == $lastCheckin->isCheckin 
                   && $locationId != $lastCheckin->locationId) {

/* Scenario 2:
 * this is a checkin event, but the last event for this user was
 * a checkin at a different location
 * we create a mock 'checkout' for this request, and 
 * set the updated_at field as current time minus a few seconds
 * BUT... in the case of duplicates, both duplicates see the 
 * last event, so both duplicates handle this the same way, and i
 * get TWO $missedCheckin records.
 */

            $missedCheckin = Checkin::create([
                'locationId' => $lastCheckin->locationId,
                'isCheckin' => false,
                'uuid' => $uuid,
                'updated_at' => time() - 10,
            ]);
        }

        // write this checkin event
        $checkin = Checkin::create([
            'locationId' => $locationId,
            'isCheckin' => $isCheckin,
            'uuid' => $uuid
        ]);

        // adjust population on another model
        $population = Population::firstOrCreate([
            'location_id' => $locationId
        ]);
        // increment or decrement population based on 
        // if this is a checkin or checkout, 
        // omitted here but mentioned as it is another 
        // database transaction on a different model

        // $responseDataSet is a dictionary with info to tell the client to present to the user
        return response()->json($responseDataSet); 
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can suspend a possible duplicate, allow the first record to go through this process, and only then allow the second one to go through (which would be seen as a duplicate)?

I tried to put in the following to wait a random number of milliseconds before processing, but it seems that the random number generator returns the same random number during the identical requests:

```
$msToSleep = 1 * random_int(500, 100000);
usleep($msToSleep);
```

The client does NOT necessarily need to know the result, so I don't need to return anything other than a 200 status code, though eventually I may want to return the valid checkin object that was created.

But I need the second request of a set of duplicate requests to see $lastCheckin being the result of the first of the duplicates, properly processed (sometimes it might be a duplicate, but separated by a few minutes), and processed accordingly.

Comment: How does the user fire two events? Wouldn't it just be easier to prevent this at the client end?

Comment: I'm not sure, trying to track this down; they're responding to location updates and posting checkin events in the background, on an asynchronous thread.

Comment: I would figure it out and fix the root issue, rather than trying to create a fix to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 has a decent [API for Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues), which may be something you'd want to check out. The asynchronous events fired from the client should be queued to prevent duplicates.

You may want to have a look at the documentation for "[Pushing Jobs Onto The Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue)" and "[Delayed Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#delayed-jobs)" in the official [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2).

Comment: This might work, as from what I understand, if I fire these off to a queue, they are executed in a synchronous manner. So, from what I understand, every request to the POST checkin would be queued, and an arbitrary response provided to the client acknowledging that the request was received; meanwhile, in the queue, do the logic required for determining if it truly is a valid checkin, or if it's a duplicate, can be performed, and the result not given to the client (or, given to the client as a push notification)?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing; configuring Laravel to use a database-driven queue, grab and manipulate input data, pass it to a worker, and return an immediate response indicating that the checkin was queued for processing. In the queue job, i perform all my validation logic, and as far as I can tell, i don't get any duplicates -- they seem to be separated by a couple seconds.